# Determinant of a $3 \times 3$ Vandermonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Let $$A = \begin{bmatrix} p^2 & p & 1\\ q^2 & q & 1\\ r^2 & r & 1\end{bmatrix}$$ Prove that $$\det(A) = (r-q)(r-p)(p-q)$$

Comment: I would use the rules of SARRUS

Comment: It is algebraic factoring. $p=q$ leaves two rows same, so Det=0,(p-q) is a factor etc.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix}p^2 & p & 1\\ q^2 & q & 1\\ r^2 & r & 1\end{vmatrix}
&=\begin{vmatrix}q^2&q\\r^2&r\end{vmatrix}-\begin{vmatrix}p^2&p\\r^2&r\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}p^2&p\\q^2&q\end{vmatrix}\\
&=(q^2r-qr^2)-(p^2r-pr^2)+(p^2q-pq^2)\\
&=q^2r-qr^2-p^2r+pr^2+p^2q-pq^2\\
&=\frac{q^2r-qr^2-p^2r+pr^2+p^2q-pq^2}{(r−q)(r−p)(p−q)}(r−q)(r−p)(p−q)\\
&=\frac{q^2r-qr^2-p^2r+pr^2+p^2q-pq^2}{q^2r-qr^2-p^2r+pr^2+p^2q-pq^2}(r−q)(r−p)(p−q)\\
&=(1)(r−q)(r−p)(p−q)=(r−q)(r−p)(p−q)\\
\end{align}